# Bash, compare Array against file and output lines not matched

Tags: bash, shell-script

I've got a string array collected from a list of log files on a RHEL machine, and I want to identify unique lines in the array that do not have an identical matching line in a file, but I can't figure it out with google :-(

This bit collecting the Array works OK

```
IFS=$'\n'

Z=( $(/usr/bin/grep -ir --exclude="*_audit.log" ' error' /var/log/*.log | grep "$(date +"%b %_d")" | grep -sv "$non_issue") )
```

I can't figure out looping through Z and checking if there is a matching line in the log file.

```
 if line in Z does not match any line in /report.log #repeat for each line in Z
  then
      echo this unique line 
fi
```

The lines of text are log file outputs so there are a lot of special characters in them like `/`, `"`, `:`, etc.

Comment: Please include a samples of the input files and the expected output.

Comment: And is that _really_ your code? Do you have a space in `Z =(...` or is that just a typo here in the question and the actual code is `Z=(...`?

Comment: No, my code was listed_errors= i just thought Z would be easier to read and added a space by mistake when i changed the name

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```bash
IFS=$'\n'
## avoid using CAPS for shell variable names since global env vars are
## capitalized by convention and if yours are also caps, you can have naming collisions
z=( $(/usr/bin/grep -ir --exclude="*_audit.log" ' error' /var/log/*.log | 
      grep "$(date +"%b %_d")" | grep -sv "$non_issue") )

for line in "${z[@]}"; do
   grep -qF "$line" /report.log &&
     printf '%s\n' "$line"
done
```

The trick is to use `-F` with `grep` which:

```
       -F, --fixed-strings
              Interpret PATTERNS as fixed strings, not regular expressions.
```

So `-F` makes `grep` treat its input as a regular string to find =, ignoring any special characters. Next, the `-q` means "don't print anything" but the whole thing will only be successful if the line is found. The `&&` means "run the next command only if the previous one was successful" and therefore, if the line is found, then we will print it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get a look at it tomorrow when i get back in the lab and add an update

Comment: Hang on, @Jay_name_goes_here, do your lines contain the file name in which they were found? I just noticed you are passing multiple input files to `grep` which usually makes it include the file name in its output (incidentally, that sort of thing is why it is important to show example input and desired output). Anyway, if that's the cae, change your first `grep` command to `/usr/bin/grep -h -ir --exclude="*_audit.log" ' error' /var/log/*.log` to tell it not to print file names.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [`comm`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/comm.1.html) command which can show the lines in one file that don't exist in the other file. Assuming that the collected strings from your log files are indeed **identical** (i.e., will match a **whole** line in `/report.log`) to the master file you are checking against, you could do this:

```bash
comm -23 <(/usr/bin/grep -ir --exclude="*_audit.log" ' error' /var/log/*.log | 
           grep "$(date +"%b %_d")" | grep -sv "$non_issue" | sort | uniq)   \
         <(sort /regions.log | uniq)
```

The command by default outputs three pieces of information: lines only in the first file, lines only in the second file, and lines in both. The `-23` switch suppresses the output of the last two, leaving you with unique lines in the first file. Note that the command expects sorted files.

---

If you are unfamiliar with the `<( <some-command-pipeline> )` syntax, that is [process substitution in `bash`](https://tecadmin.net/bash-process-substitution/). You can think of it as `bash` will pipe the output of `<some-command-pipeline>` to a temporary file, and then pass that file name to `comm`. So, this technique saves you from creating temporary files and then running the command on those files.

Here's a simple example of `comm` that translates to your problem: you want to find lines in the first file (again created via process substitution for convenience) that don't exist in the second. In this case, that would be `1`, `2` and `5`:

```bash
§ comm -23 <(echo 1 2 3 5 5 | tr ' ' '\n') <(echo 3 4 | tr ' ' '\n')
1
2
5
```